# Dell latitude d630 power shuts off instantly

Tags: hardware-failure

My Dell latitude d630 laptop has a problem of power on. Whenever we switch on the laptop, the power led stays on for 4-5 seconds and then turns off whole laptop power.

My battery is OK and charged fully.
The power adapter is also perfect.

Please tell me what to do now?

Comment: Sounds like a bad motherboard and/or CPU.

Comment: Try to remove all unneeded components. E.g. the 2nd HDD or the DVDROM from the side bay, the HDD from the bay at the bottom. If you have two SoDIMMS remove one of them. If the laptop still powers down then those are not the problem. If it works check which if the removed components causes the problem.  Also check if the fan is running (e.g. overheating shutdown).

Comment: Some systems will shutdown almost immediately if the CPU fan speed monitor shows zero RPM.

Answer (score 2):

- If the battery is as old as this laptop is, which is quite old, the battery may not actually be holding a charge (unless you tested with a battery tester), or it may have gone bad.  Try powering on the system with no battery connected.
- Do try removing your CD-ROM drive and hard drive - it's rare but possible if either of those are defective it may cause an issue.
- I don't think it's bad RAM because that will cause the Num lock key to blink on power up on this model system.
- Check openings in the laptop for corrosion - if the laptop got wet this could happen.  You could try replacing the motherboard and any components but it'd probably make more sense to buy a newer laptop.
- Dust your fans out - it may be that the CPU is overheating on power up and then powering off.  There'd have to be a lot of dust in there for this to happen though.  Also if a fan is broken as @Tog mentions this could happen.
- Open up the laptop and look near where the AC adapter connects - perhaps a power surge caused a component there to burn out of fail.  Probably looking at a motherboard repair in that situation as well.
- There's a bit of a chance that your battery is dead (unless again, you've tested with a battery tester or know this is a brand new battery that was working in another system) and the socket where the AC adapter connects to the laptop has been broken off the board - a fairly common issue on all laptops.